# R: data table group by column name vector

Tags: r, data.table

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(a = sample(c("a", "b"), 25, replace = T), b = sample(c("c", "d"), 25, replace = T), c = runif(25))
nodes <- c("a", "b")
metric <- "c"
```

Idea is to have grouping columns as dynamic variables. Where count of column names passed to `by` argument within `data.table` is not known.

Expected output (by using fixed names within the function):

```
dt[,.(Count = .N, Avg = mean(get(metric))),.(a,b)]
   a b Count       Avg
1: a c     4 0.5622371
2: b c     7 0.4535460
3: b d     6 0.5033865
4: a d     8 0.3872618
```

Going for `get()` function returns only the first argument within the nodes object:

```
dt[,.(Count = .N, Avg = mean(get(metric))),.(get(nodes))]
   get Count       Avg
1:   a    12 0.4455869
2:   b    13 0.4765493
```

It is possible to `get` names one by one and have the correct result:

```
dt[,.(Count = .N, Avg = mean(get(metric))),.(get(nodes[1]), get(nodes[2]))]
   get get.1 Count       Avg
1:   a     c     4 0.5622371
2:   b     c     7 0.4535460
3:   b     d     6 0.5033865
4:   a     d     8 0.3872618
```

But as I stated as a condition - count of these variables is not known beforehand.

Comment: You were almost there: `dt[,.(Count = .N, Avg = mean(get(metric))), mget(nodes)]`

Comment: Could you please explain difference between `.(mget(nodes))` and `mget(nodes)`? I somehow had the impression that `.(...)` notation for `by` argument is supposed to be a convenient way to pass multiple arguments.

Comment: `.` is an alias for `list`. `mget` already returns a list.

Answer (score 2):

We can specify the grouping variable with `nodes` alone and the columns to get the mean in `.SDcols`

```
dt[, .(Count = .N, Avg = mean(.SD[[1]])), by = nodes, .SDcols = metric]
#   a b Count       Avg
#1: a c     4 0.5622371
#2: b c     7 0.4535460
#3: b d     6 0.5033865
#4: a d     8 0.3872618
```

Comment: It looks like the `c` is not needed. For example, `e = substitute(.(Count = .N, Avg = mean(metric)), list(metric = as.symbol(metric))); dt[, eval(e), by=nodes]`